# Botman, debian 9, port 8000 : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: debian, port

I'm currently trying to install a botman on a debian 9 server.
I install botman, launch the botman server with success :

```
    # php artisan serve
    Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
    [Fri Jan 17 12:28:12 2020] PHP 7.4.1 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
```

But when I try to reach the http://[myserverIP]:8000 my browser tells me "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

I tried :

```
nc -l 8000
```

without any response, as my terminal doesn't return anything. I had to stop the command after a while.

I precise that I have no firewall.

To tell the truth I'm not very good in server management (to say the least).

Someone can help me on that ? Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is most likely that your Botman server is only listening on the local IP (127.0.0.1). You need to reconfigure Botman to listen on your server's IP.

Comment: You're totally right... I feel stupid. I check it. Thanks.